# Checkstyle can't find suppressions.xml

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

I'm using Gradle 5.0 and Checkstyle 8.15.  I have a Java project with the following Checkstyle config and suppressions files:

- config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml
- config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml

`checkstyle.xml` references `suppressions.xml` like so:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

If I run checkstyle against my source, it fails:

> $ ./gradlew checkstyleMain -xwebpack
>
> - Configure project : Defaulting to dev Spring profile
>
>   Task :checkstyleMain FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':checkstyleMain'.
>   Unable to create Root Module: config {/Users/robert/dev/...},
>   classpath
>   {/Users/robert/dev/...}.
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 6.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s 3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date

If I remove the reference to `suppressions.xml`, the build completes (checkstyle finds errors that would have been ignored if the suppressions were discovered).

My understanding from the doc is that the root for referenced files like `config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml` is the project root.  That doesn't seem to be the case however.

Am I not setting up checkstyle properly?

Comment: Using a similar setup worked fine for me. I have a `config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml` and `config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml`. I reference the `suppressions.xml` as you have listed as well in my `checkstyle.xml`. The file is added to the classpath and loaded properly, and the checkstyle tool indeed skips out on the items listed. I ran the cmd `gradle check` from the root project directory.

Answer (score 13):

If you are placing suppressions.xml inside project-dir/config/checkstyle/ , please use the following way,

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${config_loc}/suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

Latest version of checkstyle has config_loc variable set as project-dir/config/checkstyle/ automatically.